# Clipping in MKOverlayView:drawMapRect

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mapkit

I'm having an issue with drawing to areas outside of the `MKMapRect` passed to `drawMapRect:mapRect:zoomScale:inContext` in my `MKOverlayView` derived class.  I'm trying to draw a triangle for each coordinate in a collection and the problem occurs when the coordinate is near the edge of the `MKMapRect`.  See the below image for an example of the problem.

[image]

In the image, the light red boxes indicate the `MKMapRect` being rendered in each call to `drawMapRect`.  The problem is illustrated in the red circle where, as you can see, only part of the triangle is being rendered.  I'm assuming that its being clipped to the `MKMapRect`, though the documentation for `MKOverlayView:drawMapRect` makes me think this shouldn't be happening.

From the documentation:

> You should also not make assumptions that the view’s frame matches the bounding rectangle of the overlay. The view’s frame is actually bigger than the bounding rectangle to allow you to draw lines for things like roads that might be located directly on the border of that rectangle.

My current solution is to draw objects more than once if they are in a maprect that is slightly larger than then maprect given to drawMapRect but this causes me to draw some things more than needed.

Does anyone know of a way to increase the size of the clipping area in drawMapRect so this isn't an issue?  Any other suggestions are also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up adding a buffer to the rect passed in to drawMapRect:mapRect:zoomScale:inContext and using that to determine which objects to draw.  This results in more objects being drawn than needed, but not by much.